# Which tag question is right for this sentence?

Tags: questions, expression-choice, question-tags

> Nowadays the only thing people seem to be interested in is earning more and more money, ____ ?
>
> a) don't they
>   b) isn't it
>   c) don't you
>   d) will you

Please explain which is the correct tag question.

Comment: In my country(Uzbekistan), Questions and their types are one of subject lesson in my school. I know, in The UK and in  other countries,  where English language is being taught, know about TAG questions and it is included in the school system's education. What I want to say is that I need help of native English people. Thanks a lot

Comment: (1) FYI / FWIW, I grew up in the US, and I don’t remember being taught about question tags or tag questions in school (except in French class, where we learned about [“n’est-ce pas”](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/n%27est-ce_pas)). I don’t even remember learning the *term* “question tag”. Of course we learned how to use question tags in English by listening to people talk. (2) I agree that “isn’t it” is the best of the four choices you listed. But, realistically, people would just say “…, right?”. Other options include “…, isn’t that so?”, “…, isn’t that true?”, “…, isn’t that the case?”, etc.

Comment: Scott, thanks for commenting. I want to enter university, faculty of learning international languages, and in exams there are a lot of questions about Tag question. Thus, I improve my skills... Thanks a lot..

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It would be 'isn't it?'
In this case 'Thing' is your subject 'is' main verb - the sentence is positive so the question tag is going to be negative.